# How to match the first column in a text file and display all lines upto and including the matched line?

Tags: awk

Contents of my file, test

```
836 3368839 3368410 123456  
838 3368399 3368419 123456  
839 3368425 3368425 123456  
936 3368435 3368435 123456  
937 3368441 3368441 123456
```

$ col_match=839

Just to test my script, I now set the bash variable col_match to match the line number
and then only print out the first three lines.

```
$ awk '{print} $1=="839"{exit}' test.out    ---> I want this
836 3368839 3368410 123456  
838 3368399 3368419 123456  
839 3368425 3368425 123456
```

But what I really need to do is set the variable col_match, when I do, I get this

```
$ awk '{print} $1==$col_match{exit}' test.out
836 3368839 3368410 123456  
838 3368399 3368419 123456  
839 3368425 3368425 123456  
936 3368435 3368435 123456  
937 3368441 3368441 123456
```

How can I use the variable, `$col_match` instead of the literal string value?

Comment: Your code would work, but you must make `col_match` and `awk` variable, not a shell variable. e.g. `awk -v col_match=839 '{print} $1==col_match {exit}' test.out`

Comment: `"$col_match"` is literal for *string* `$col_match` (observe it is delimited by `"`), whilst you are using GNU `AWK` variable name it should not be enclosed in `"`.

Comment: is it possible for multiple lines to have the same value in the 1st field/column?

Comment: @markp-fuso The first column is the line number, so it would only occur once in the file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin My issue is not knowing how to convert the shell variable, col_match to an awk variable. I need to supply the shell variable and not the literal 839, since that was obtained by looking for the the line number match in another file.

Comment: @jackcardozo passing a shell variable to `awk` takes the form: `awk -v awk_var1="$shell_var1" -v awk_var2="$shell_var2" ... -v awk_varN="$shell_varN" '.... awk script ....'`; Daweo's answer shows this where both `awk_var1` and `shell_var1` are replaced with `col_match`

Comment: @jackcardozo Sorry for not being clear -- that what `awk -v col_match=839` does.... or replace `839` with `"$your_shell_var"`. The `-v` says make `awk_var = some_value` where `some_value` can be a direct value or shell variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it simply using the default rule (`print`) and then the special case for line that matches `col_match` being `print; exit`, e.g.

```bash
awk -v col_match=839 '$1 == col_match {print; exit}1' file
```

The `1` at the end of the expression is just shorthand for the default rule `print`, which prints every line. So it prints every record (line) in the file until `col_match` is reached at which time you need an explicit `print` as `exit` would cause the default rule to be skipped.

**Example Use/Output**

With your data in the file `dat/cols.txt` that would be:

```
$ awk -v col_match=839 '$1 == col_match {print; exit}1' dat/cols.txt
836 3368839 3368410 123456
838 3368399 3368419 123456
839 3368425 3368425 123456
```

**Using** `sed`

You can actually do it in a slightly shorter manner with `sed` using a range expression, e.g.

```bash
col_match=839; sed -n "1,/^$col_match /p" file
```

The space after `$col_match` in the range expression ensure only `839` and not `83925`, etc.. is matched.

(same output)

Comment: and eliminating the explicit `print`: `'1; $1 == col_match {exit}'`

Answer (score 1):

> How to match the first column in a text file and display all lines
> upto and including the matched line?

In GNU `AWK` you might use [range](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Ranges.html) for this task, let `test.out` content be

```
836 3368839 3368410 123456  
838 3368399 3368419 123456  
839 3368425 3368425 123456  
936 3368435 3368435 123456  
937 3368441 3368441 123456
```

then you might write code with hard-coded value 839 as follows

```
awk 'NR==1,$1=="839"' test.out
```

then upgrade it to make use variable

```
col_match="839"
awk -v col_match=$col_match 'NR==1,$1==col_match' test.out
```

both would give output

```
836 3368839 3368410 123456  
838 3368399 3368419 123456  
839 3368425 3368425 123456
```

Explantion: range consist of starting condition and ending condition separated by `,`, its' action is applied to all line from one which meets starting condition to one which meets ending condition (inclusive), in this case as starting condition I set is 1st row (`NR==1`) and ending condition is 1st column is `839`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: the hard-coded string literal 839 was just to aid in testing my script line. I do need to use the equivalent of the bash variable col_match which happens to be set to 839.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the same filtering effect without explicit `print` statement or `regular expressions` :

```
echo '
836 3368839 3368410 123456
838 3368399 3368419 123456
839 3368425 3368425 123456
936 3368435 3368435 123456
937 3368441 3368441 123456 ' |
```

---

```
gawk '_{ exit } __!=$!_ || --_' __='839'

nawk 'NR==!_, "839" == $!_'              #  more succinct
                                         #  but w/o early exit

mawk '_{exit}(_-=__==$!_)_' __='839'     ## update : shortest form
                                         ##          w/ early exit

mawk '_{exit}(_-=__==$!_)_' __="$col_match"
```

---

```
836 3368839 3368410 123456  
838 3368399 3368419 123456  
839 3368425 3368425 123456
```

> 

even shorter but potentially incorrectly skipping items —- *for illustration purposes only - not recommended*

```
nawk '_$!-_ <= "839"'
```

---

```
836 3368839 3368410 123456  
838 3368399 3368419 123456 
9̵3̵ ̵3̵3̵6̵8̵4̵2̵5̵ ̵3̵3̵6̵8̵4̵2̵5̵ ̵1̵2̵3̵4̵5̵6̵   <—- incorrectly skips this line
839 3368425 3368425 123456
```

Comment: I want to use the equivalent of the bash variable col_match that I previously calculated, instead of the literal string "839"

Comment: @jackcardozo : so ? i already parameterized my answer before :  change  ::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::: ::::::   `gawk '_{ exit } __ != _$!_ || ++_' __='839'` to :::::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::: :::::::: ::::::::: `gawk '_{ exit } __ != _$!_ || ++_' __="$someshellvar"` … whcih reminded me i could further optimize it

Answer (score 0):

Drew some inspiration from all of you and figured out what I needed to do. Thx to all.

awk -v col="$col_match" '{print} $1==col {exit}' test.out